# querying elasticsearch with just OR, AND, NOT leads to a 500 error

Tags: elasticsearch

I know those are reserved words in elasticsearch, but I want to know if there's a way around this problem. It would be nice if I were able to handle this a bit less heavy handedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query_string query is very restrictive. If you are using it with user's queries you should add logic to handle syntax error in your application. One of the simplest ways of handling this situation is to catch the error on the web server side (or whatever side is sitting between elasticsearch and user), place the failed user's query into the [match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/) query with `_all` field and rerun the query. It will provide a meaningful fallback mechanism for queries with syntax errors.